# 'Where' clause with conditional 'Contains'

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The following will select persons which have the keyword contained by **both** FirstName and LastName

```
                if (searchFields.Contains("FirstName"))
                {
                    query = query.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(keyword));
                }

                if (searchFields.Contains("LastName"))
                {
                    query= query.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(keyword));
                }
```

How can I change it such that it will select persons with keyword contained by **either** FirstName or LastName ?

In other words I am looking for an OR clause, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 3):

```
bool searchFirstName = searchFields.Contains("FirstName");
bool searchLastName = searchFields.Contains("LastName");
if (searchFirstName && searchLastName)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(keyword) 
                          || p.LastName.Contains(keyword));
}
else if(searchFirstName)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(keyword));
} 
else if(searchLastName)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(keyword));
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. It works for 2 columns, but for anything larger code is messy. I found what I was looking for, see my answer. Unless you have a better idea

Comment: @MikeFills: if you find that more readable and maintainable use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I needed:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

It is using LINQ expressions, it combines them using Expression.Or